# How can i make loop timer?

Tags: c#, timer, infinite-loop, windows-forms-designer

I want to make time loop label in panel with timer but how ?
I got this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.AutoSize = true;
    label3.Text = label3.Text;
    label3.Parent = panel1;
    label3.Location = new Point(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height / 2 - (label3.Height / 2));
    timer1.Start();
}
```

and

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label3.Right < 0)
    {
        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(panel1.ClientSize.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Left -= 10;
    }
}
```

How to i make infinite time loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the StopWatch class inside a Do...While loop

```
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        long time;
        sw.Start();

        do
        {
            time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        } while (time < 10000); //ten seconds
```